# Win server 2003: bind netbios name to ip address

Tags: windows-server-2003, netbios

I have a Win 2003 enterprise edition cluster. Each group of resources has its own ip address and network name.

Here is the result of **nbtstat -n**:

```
Public LAN(1):
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.7] Scope Id: []

            NetBIOS Local Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
LUWIN5         <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
LUWIN5         <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
SERCHIO        <00>  GROUP       Registered
SERCHIO        <1E>  GROUP       Registered
LUWIN5         <03>  UNIQUE      Registered
RISERVA        <03>  UNIQUE      Registered

\Device\NetBt_If1:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.15] Scope Id: []

            NetBIOS Local Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
SQLSERVER      <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
SQLSERVER      <00>  UNIQUE      Registered

\Device\NetBt_If2: Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.16] Scope Id: []

            NetBIOS Local Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
VDISKING       <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
VDISKING       <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
```

I would like to have a similar configuration (multiple Ip each of which with its netbios name) on an another server. I know how to add other ip addresses, but I don't know how to bind them to new netbios names.
Any help ?

Comment: Kinda tricky. Perhaps you should check some AD documentation.  
Now, this is the basic. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457118.aspx

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/networking/how-can-i-define-multiple-netbios-names-machine

Comment: @mootmoot I had already read that page but I want to bind a name to a specific ip. In the **nbtstat** output you can see different names for different ips.

Comment: Seems you must have the windows DNS name server to enabled it. 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/06/04/multiple-names-for-one-computer-consolidate-your-smb-file-servers-without-breaking-unc-paths/